# update subdocument php mondodb library

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to update a subdocument but  I'm deleting  the previous content, nad that I need its like an array push

```
$app->post('/addWidget', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $mongo = new Connection();
    $conn = $mongo->getConnection();
    $post_data = $request->getParsedBody();
    $result = $conn->find( [ 'user' => $post_data['user']], ['projection'=>['widgets'=>1]])->toArray();
    var_dump($result[0]['widgets']);
    $updateResult = $conn->updateOne(
        [ 'user' => $post_data['user'] ],
        [ '$set' => [ 'widgets' => [["name"=>$post_data['name'], "color"=>$post_data['color']]]]]
    );
});
```

It's posible to update a subdocument with `updateOne` function?

Comment: Are you trying to add new fields to a subdocument or to add a new document to an array of subdocuments?

Comment: new document to an array of subdocuments

Answer (score 0):

As you want to push documents to an array, you need [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push) instead of `$set`.

```
$updateResult = $conn->updateOne(
    [ 'user' => $post_data['user'] ],
    [ 
        '$push' => [
            'widgets' => [
                [
                    "name"=>$post_data['name'],
                    "color"=>$post_data['color']
                ]
            ]
        ] 
    ]
);
```